# Camera issue between galaxy note pro and galaxy note 2

Tags: android, android-camera, galaxy

I've created a custom camera app and I installed it on both and they're not working similarly.

When I touch the screen of the galaxy note 2, the image freezes whereas on the note pro, it just resumes and doesn't freezes.

What seems to be issue or I should look out for?

They're using the same codes to take a photo.

```
preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            View view = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.picture);
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            view.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
            saveBitmap(bitmap);
            view.destroyDrawingCache();               
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) states clearly:

> 8. After taking a picture, preview display will have stopped. To take more photos, call startPreview() again first

Note Pro does not stop display, but this is not a standard behaviour.

Comment: Just noticed this on a Samsung Galaxy S6. Can you confirm that this is default behavior for some Samsung devices?

Comment: @ChristophPacher: no I cannot confirm such statement, even for "some" Samsung devices. The question is, why does this question bother you? Does the non-standard behavior on *some Samsung devices* require some special non-standard treatment?

Comment: yes it does. i want the preview to stop when taking a picture. when stopping the preview manually my ui thread is blocking and when stopping the preview in a background thread the stop is delayed too much.

Comment: @ChristophPacher: auch, this hurts. So, if you call `camera.stopPreview()` on your S6, the thread blocks? Or it blocks only if you call after `camera.takePicture()`? Or from `onPicturetaken()` callback?

Comment: camera.stopPreview() in the ui thread blocks and makes my anmiations stutter.

Comment: @ChristophPacher: this is a case worth opening a separate question on SO  and an issue on Samsung forums. I never encountered a system where stopPreview() or startPreview() would not return immediately.

Comment: @ChristophPacher: looking at the code, there *may be* a problem with **mAutoFocusCallbackLock**.

Answer (score 0):

> When I touch the screen of the galaxy note 2, the image freezes whereas on the note pro, it just resumes and doesn't freezes.

The Camera APIs are hardware-related, and thus they may perform differently on different devices.

> using the same codes to take a photo

You should take the photo in Callback:

```
Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback(){
   onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      try {
                  FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/preview.jpg");
                  output.write(data);
                  output.flush();
                  output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
   }
};
public void onClick(View v) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);             
}
```